# Moodle - How to remove Front Page Settings from a role

Tags: moodle

I've added a new Role that's able to configure some of the module from Site Administration. But I can't seem to find a way to remove "Front Page" from the role. Has anyone able to done this before? Below is the picture of said module that I need to remove.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the code (https://github.com/moodle/moodle/blob/master/admin/settings/frontpage.php#L8), the frontpage settings are available to any user who is a **site admin** or who has one of the **following capabilities** at the level of the frontpage course (or at the system level above that):

- moodle/course:update
- moodle/role:assign
- moodle/restore:restorecourse
- moodle/backup:backupcourse
- moodle/course:managefiles
- moodle/question:add
- moodle/question:editmine
- moodle/question:editall
- moodle/question:viewmine
- moodle/question:viewall
- moodle/question:movemine
- moodle/question:moveall

Comment: So if I'm the site admin, there's no way to remove the Frontpage settings right? It seems like I'll have to do the changes at the code level then. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, as is standard, is someone is a site admin they get access to everything (including bypassing all other checks). If you want someone to be a 'site admin', but with limitations, you should really consider using the 'manager' role instead.

Comment: Hmmm. It seems like I'm already using the 'manager' role but I've also allowed it to have moodle/site:configview . Is this the only way to configure the frontpage settings?

Comment: You might be able to override the manager role in the front page context and set all the capabilities listed in my reply to "prevent" (I don't have Moodle in front of me right now to check)

Comment: Ah, you're basically right! I forgot to change my role to manager and by Not Allowing all the capabilities as you mentioned above, the Frontpage Settings is no longer there. I wish I could upvote you but my reputation's not enough. Thanks!